# How to compare Resultset.getString() to String in Java?

Tags: java, string, resultset

I'm trying to compare a resultset to a string, but can't seem to get it to work. This is is what I'm trying:

```
if(resultset.getString("name").equals("George"))
```

When I printout `resultset.getString("name")` I get George. So they should be equal?

I also have a comparator using `resultset.getInt("Age")` that works, so I thought maybe I could be clever and use *compareTo* instead of *equeals*, but when I try,

```
if(resultset.getString("name").comparesTo("George"))
```

I was expecting to get 0, but I get 93???

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe the `String` returned contains whitespace or other invisible characters.

Comment: Great incite! I'll try triming the resultset before comparing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `.equals` does not show them to be equal, then there is a difference. Could there be a space after one of them, or perhaps some other extra character?

Try printing both of them surrounded by a known character, maybe something like:

```
System.out.println("*" + resultset.getString("name") + "*");
```

Also, as a dummy check, make sure `getString` is actually returning type String. If this is a method you've defined, it could be returning something strange.

Comment: That was exactly the issue, there was traling spaces. It looks like the restultset string filled up with the database entry size. The table allows for Char(100), and there where 94 spaces (minus the characters from George). A *trim* fixed the issue.

`if(resultset.getString("name").equals("George").trim())`